# Do you need a license for US military badges, awards, decorations?

Tags: licensing

We would like to use in our game names and images of real US military badges, awards and decoration.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awards_and_decorations_of_the_United_States_military
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badges_of_the_United_States_Navy

I would like to know, if they are copyrighted or protected in any other way, or are they considered to be in public domain.

Regards and thanks
Piotr

Comment: The description of all the images on these Wikipedia articles says they are in the public domain because they are work of the U.S. federal government. However, just because Wikipedia claims they may use them doesn't mean that the DoD shares their view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need a license. But, to be on the safe side...

you can actually call the army (as I understand it they assist with other branches as well) and ask questions like these, for free! They can also assist with other things, like where insignia are supposed to go, how they're arranged, uniform standards, etc.

[Department of the Army's Office of the Chief of Public Affairs](http://www.army.mil/info/institution/publicAffairs/ocpa-west/faq.html)

```
U.S. Army Office of the Chief of Public Affairs, Western Region 
10880 Wilshire Boulevard, Suite 1250 
Los Angeles, California 90024 
Phone: (310) 235-7621 
Fax: (310) 235-6075
```

Comment: See Army Regulation 670-1 (commonly known as AR 670-1) for wear and appearance of the military uniform.